# How do i get connection with mqsql server inside intelliJ Idea

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

When i try to get connection from SQL server inside intelliJ Idea, ClassNotFoundException was coming. Driver Class has located in same folder. Please give me a solution.
[There is my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/941l5.jpg)

[There is my src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQNlb.jpg)

I used singleton design pattern for get sql Connection.

```
package sample;
import java.sql.*;

class DBConnection{
    private static DBConnection obj;
    private Connection con;

    private DBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ijse","root","apple");
    }

    public static DBConnection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        if(obj==null){
            obj = new DBConnection();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        return con;
    }
}
```

This is controller view class

```
package sample;
import java.sql.*;

public class DataControll {
    public static boolean addEmployee(Object e) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        String query = "Insert into employee values(?,?)";
        Connection con = DBConnection.createConnection().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement(query);
        state.setObject(1,e.getId());
        state.setObject(2,e.getName());
        return state.executeUpdate()>0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added your jdbc jar as an external dependency/library?

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `Class.forName()` must be a [fully qualified class name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)), so in your case I think it should be:

```
Class.forName("sample.Driver");
```